# How to add post thumbnail on home page in MODx Revo?

Tags: php, thumbnails, modx, modx-revolution

I'm new to MODx. Adding in the post thumbnail creates a visual association for each post or page. How to add post thumbnail on homepage?  How to show first image in the post as thumbnail on home page?

As a to WordPress:

[image]

Comment: You want modx to act like wordpress?

Comment: WordPress just as an example. Illustration of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions

1. Create image tv, and manually set image every time when creating a resource.
2. Create an input filter and apply it to the content field -

snippet `get_first_image`:

```
<?php
preg_match('/<img[^<>]+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"][^<>]*>/i', $input, $image);
return $image['src'];
```

and to get image in main page template:

```
<img src="[[+content:get_first_image]]">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use modx as a blogging platform you should look int installing Articles, Archivist & phpthumbof - these packages will provide all the tools & snippets you need to get that done. [If not Vasis's solution will be far easier]

Comment: ...and here's some documentation to help you get started: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Articles. You'll get a lot more help here if you at least attempt something before asking for help :)